# Sending smart pointer to protobaf. Memory issue

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, smart-pointers

I use protobuf as a data format for the network communications.

In my data model has WrapperMessage, wrapper which includes sub message RegistrationRequest and InputChecking.

Somewhere in the program I create one type of message (RegistrationRequest / InputChecking) then passing it on function templates to include it in WrapperMessage then serialize and send.

But something was wrong with my pointer? malloc/new/whatever detects heap corruption ?? I do not understand that, why he does not want to take mes.get () and falls at runtime..

error: Critical error detected c0000374

all code of my test program:

```
#include "ProtobufDataModels.pb.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

template <class T>
static void SendProto(T * message);

template <class T>
void SendProto(T * message)
{
    WrapperMessage wm;

    if (std::is_same<T, InputChecking>::value)
    {
        std::shared_ptr<InputChecking> mes(message);

        std::string msg;
        message->SerializeToString(&msg);
        std::cout << msg << std::endl; // all ok

        // set inputChecking mes. to wrapperMessage
        wm.set_allocated_mes_inputchecking(mes.get()); // crash here

    }
    else if (std::is_same<T, RegistrationRequest>::value)
    {
    }

}

int main()
{
    InputChecking * inputChecking = new InputChecking();
    inputChecking->set_login("Jack");

    SendProto(inputChecking);

    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code above, you transfer ownership of `message` object to both `shared_ptr` and protobuf `wm` object. This is incorrect. Both of them delete this object when end of scope is reached, with second deletion causing error. The easiest way to fix it is to use `message` pointer directly without creating `shared_ptr` at all.